# How to send multi-line message to team's channel via Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I want to send multi-line message to a team's channel via the following [Graph API (Beta)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http):

`POST /teams/{id}/channels/{id}/messages`

I've tried sending the following via `chatMessage.body`, but I'm still getting everything in one line.

```
{
  "contentType": "text",
  "content": "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3"
}
```

and

```
{
  "contentType": "text",
  "content": "Line 1\r\nLine 2\r\nLine 3"
}
```

Do I miss anything here or is this not supported yet?

Update:

I'd want to achieve multi-line content with `contentType` as `text`.

Comment: `"content": "Line 1<br/>Line 2<br/>Line 3"` helps?

Comment: Hi @Arulkumar, thank you for your comment. The output is the same as is without new line, using your suggested content. I'd want to stick to `contentType` as `text` though.

Comment: @Ivan Where you able to make this work? Seems like only `contentType` as `application/json` is supported... haven't found a way to send a multiline message yet :(

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

```
{
  "contentType": "html",
  "content": "Line 1<br/>\nLine 2"
}
```

Comment: Hi @Deepak, thank you for your response. I'd want to stick to `contentType` as `text` though. Updated my question for this.

Comment: Why do you want to use content type as text? You can still use text content just use <br> as line breaks. I don't see any side effects.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

`Line 1\n\nLine2`